# pointer to byte[] to std::unique_ptr<type, custom_deleter> does not compile

Tags: c++

I have a type which should get deleted with a custom deleter.
For the allocation I use placement new with byte[].

Also I want to return a unique_ptr on allocation.
Unfortunately the allocation does not work.

I tried this:

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter>
allocate_node(const std::string& value, int levels)
{
    // get size of Skip_node
    const auto node_size =
        sizeof(CustomType) + (levels - 1) * sizeof(CustomType*);

    // allocate memory
    std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> node = std::make_unique<std::byte[]>(node_size);

    // construct object in allocated space
    new (node.get()) CustomType{value, levels, {nullptr}};

    // transform byte[] into std::unique_ptr<Skip_node*, Skip_node_deleter>
    return {reinterpret_cast<CustomType*>(node.release())};  //does not work
}
```

Unfortunately the last line does not work. I would have expected we transform byte[] into std::unique_ptr<Skip_node*, Skip_node_deleter> but I get this compilation error:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../untitled -I. -I../Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../untitled/main.cpp
../untitled/main.cpp: In function ‘std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter> allocate_node(const string&, int)’:
../untitled/main.cpp:38:58: error: could not convert ‘{((CustomType*)node.std::unique_ptr<std::byte []>::release())}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter>’
   38 |     return {reinterpret_cast<CustomType*>(node.release())};  //does not work
      |                                                          ^
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          <brace-enclosed initializer list>
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/memory:83,
                 from ../untitled/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = CustomType*; _Dp = CustomTypeDeleter]’:
../untitled/main.cpp:43:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:357:56: error: static assertion failed: unique_ptr's deleter must be invocable with a pointer
  357 |  static_assert(__is_invocable<deleter_type&, pointer>::value,
      |                                                        ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:361:17: error: no match for call to ‘(std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter>::deleter_type {aka CustomTypeDeleter}) (std::remove_reference<CustomType**&>::type)’
  361 |    get_deleter()(std::move(__ptr));
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../untitled/main.cpp:13:10: note: candidate: ‘void CustomTypeDeleter::operator()(CustomType*) const’
   13 |     void operator()(CustomType* p) const noexcept
      |          ^~~~~~~~
../untitled/main.cpp:13:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::remove_reference<CustomType**&>::type’ {aka ‘CustomType**’} to ‘CustomType*’
   13 |     void operator()(CustomType* p) const noexcept
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
make: *** [Makefile:725: main.o] Error 1
11:55:23: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Minimal Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

struct CustomType {
    std::string value;
    int levels;
    CustomType* next[1];
};

class CustomTypeDeleter {
public:
    void operator()(CustomType* p) const noexcept
    {
        if (p) {
            p->~CustomType();

            auto raw_p = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(p);
            delete[] raw_p;
        }
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter>
allocate_node(const std::string& value, int levels)
{
    // get size of Skip_node
    const auto node_size =
        sizeof(CustomType) + (levels - 1) * sizeof(CustomType*);

    // allocate memory
    std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> node = std::make_unique<std::byte[]>(node_size);

    // construct object in allocated space
    new (node.get()) CustomType{value, levels, {nullptr}};

    // transform byte[] into std::unique_ptr<Skip_node*, Skip_node_deleter>
    return {reinterpret_cast<CustomType*>(node.release())};  //does not work
}

int main()
{
    auto node = allocate_node("test", 3);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a `std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter>` and not a `std::unique_ptr<CustomType, CustomTypeDeleter>`?

Comment: Also, why are you creating a `std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]>` instead of allocating memory with `new` or `malloc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `std::unique_ptr<CustomType, CustomTypeDeleter>` (not a `std::unique_ptr<CustomType*, CustomTypeDeleter>`) and you need a deleter instance:

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomType, CustomTypeDeleter>
allocate_node(const std::string& value, int levels)
{
    //...
    return {reinterpret_cast<CustomType*>(node.release()), CustomTypeDeleter{}};
}
```

Full function:

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomType, CustomTypeDeleter>
allocate_node(const std::string& value, unsigned levels) {
    // get size of Skip_node
    const auto node_size = sizeof(CustomType) + (levels - 1U) * sizeof(CustomType*);

    // allocate memory
    auto raw = new std::byte[node_size];

    // construct object in allocated space
    auto rv = new(raw) CustomType{value, levels}; // use return value from new
    std::fill_n(rv->next, levels - 1U, nullptr); // set all to nullptr, not only one

    return {rv, CustomTypeDeleter{}};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xjvEY3)

Just be aware of that accessing `next` out of bounds has undefined behavior (although it'll *probably* work).

Also, the array objects haven't technically started their lifetime until you `new` them.

Here's an alternative that wouldn't make the program have undefined behavior:

```
struct CustomType {
    std::string value;
    unsigned levels;
    CustomType** const next; // not a CustomType*[]
};

template<typename T, typename ArrT>
class CustomTypeDeleter {
public:
    void operator()(T* p) const noexcept {
        if(p) {
            p->~T(); // main object destructor

            // call destructor on an array of objects
            for(size_t i=0; i < p->levels; ++i) p->next[i].~ArrT();

            // delete memory
            delete[] reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(p);            
        }
    }
};

static std::unique_ptr<CustomType, CustomTypeDeleter<CustomType, CustomType*>> 
allocate_node(const std::string& value, unsigned levels) {

    // get size of Skip_node
    auto node_arr_align = std::max(sizeof(CustomType), sizeof(CustomType*));
    auto node_size = node_arr_align + levels * sizeof(CustomType*);

    // allocate memory
    auto raw = new std::byte[node_size];

    // start lifetime of array objects
    auto arr = new(raw + node_arr_align) CustomType*[levels]{};

    // construct object in allocated space
    auto rv = new(raw) CustomType{value, levels, arr}; // use return value from new

    return {rv, CustomTypeDeleter<CustomType, CustomType*>{}}; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort of write this in deep answer. I'm not sure if the next objects should be deleted that would mean that the object it points to is deleted as well. The next is like a pointer to the next `CustomTypes`. It is only a reference to navigate to the next `CustomType`. Linking looks similar to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#/media/File:Skip_list.svg.

Comment: @Sandro4912 You are welcome! The objects that the pointers in the `next` "array" points at will not be deleted in any of the implementations above. The second implementation does what the first one does, but it avoids accessing the array out-of-bounds (which made the program have UB) and it also starts and ends the lifetime of the pointer objects (probably overkill) - but not the actual objects that the pointers are pointing at.